# Is there a way to detect nvidia driver version with java code (maybe using jogl)?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I tried to use jogl, but I could not find out how to do that.
It seems like a basic functionality, but I saw no documentation about it.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't have this functionality, except for `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` which may or may not contain the driver version in the vendor-specific information part. You have to query either the driver management system on your OS or (for Tesla and Quadro) use NVML

Comment: Yes, it's possible, we do it internally and you can get this information by following more or less BDL's advice, the driver version number often appears in GL_RENDERER, GL_VERSION and/or elsewhere. No it's not a basic feature as there is no standard way of indicating the driver version number. Please rather ask your JOGL specific question on our official forum as only a few contributors and maintainers come here.